# jboss7 upgrade + seam + jsf Configuration Failed error on deployment

Tags: jsf, jboss7.x, seam

I'm currently upgrading my Jboss5 project to Jboss7.  As of now, we still have seam2 and jsf 1.2 integrated into the project.  Those will eventually be phased out/upgraded, but for now I just need the application to deploy.  I've worked through a ton of bugs, but am stuck on this one:

```
   16:53:49,285 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].
    [default-host].[/xxx]] (MSC service thread 1-1) Exception sending 
    context initialized event to listener instance of class 
    com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamApplicationFactory
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:215) [jsf-impl-1.2_15-jbossorg-2.jar:1.2_15.jbossorg-1-20111019-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:200) [jsf-impl-1.2_15-jbossorg-2.jar:1.2_15.jbossorg-1-20111019-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]

   Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamApplicationFactory
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:364) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinder.java:537) [jsf-api-1.2_15-jbossorg-2.jar:1.2_15.jbossorg-1-20111019-SNAPSHOT]
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getImplementationInstance(FactoryFinder.java:405) [jsf-api-1.2_15-jbossorg-2.jar:1.2_15.jbossorg-1-20111019-SNAPSHOT]
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.access$400(FactoryFinder.java:135) [jsf-api-1.2_15-jbossorg-2.jar:1.2_15.jbossorg-1-20111019-SNAPSHOT]
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:717) [jsf-api-1.2_15-jbossorg-2.jar:1.2_15.jbossorg-1-20111019-SNAPSHOT]
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:239) [jsf-api-1.2_15-jbossorg-2.jar:1.2_15.jbossorg-1-20111019-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:187) [jsf-impl-1.2_15-jbossorg-2.jar:1.2_15.jbossorg-1-20111019-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:132) [jsf-impl-1.2_15-jbossorg-2.jar:1.2_15.jbossorg-1-20111019-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:205) [jsf-impl-1.2_15-jbossorg-2.jar:1.2_15.jbossorg-1-20111019-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 9 more

    16:53:49,338 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-1) Error listenerStart
    16:53:49,340 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-1) Context [/xxx] startup failed due to previous errors
    16:53:49,354 INFO  [org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler] (MSC service thread 1-1) Scheduler xxxScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED shutting down.
    16:53:49,356 INFO  [org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler] (MSC service thread 1-1) Scheduler xxxScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED paused.
    16:53:49,361 INFO  [org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler] (MSC service thread 1-1) Scheduler xxxScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED shutdown complete.

   16:53:49,380 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./xxx: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./xxx: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:95)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
```

I've read that the cause might be some jar conflicts, but I'm struggling to find out which ones are causing problems.  The project was previously running with jsf 2.2 (I believe, definitely something over 2), but I downgraded it to 1.2 for the time being due to a conflict with Seam 2.0.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

**Update**

I should have been more specific - I am upgrading to JBoss 7.1.1

Comment: I think this link is a good thread to address your issue:   https://developer.jboss.org/blogs/marek-novotny/2011/07/29/seam-2-booking-example-on-jboss-as-7

Comment: Hi Anup, thanks for the reply.  I am actually using Jboss 7.1.1. and in the link, the guy seemed to solve this by using the updated version of 7.0.x.  Correct me if I am wrong, but I believe any updates made in any 7.0.x version should already have been included in 7.1.1

Comment: 'jboss' 10.1 is already out... it is called wildfly and was release august last year. Are you sure you want to upgrade to 7.1.1?

Comment: Yes, for the time being, due to other constraints outside of my control, we have to upgrade to Jboss 7.1.1

Comment: Did you find any solution?? I am in the same boat.

Comment: @SushilBehera: wildfly 16 is already out!